# migrating a document library from sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint 2013 without using 3rd party tools

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library

I have to migrate a document library from sharepoint 2010 to sharepoint 2013 without using any 3rd party tool. any nice approach to achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

Their are 3 ways to get this done.

- Export from 2010 and import in 2013(with little tricks)
- Content Database Migration
- 3rd party tools.

**Method 1.**

- Export the list from SharePoint 2010 using either the Central
  Administration or PowerShell (Export-SPWeb). In the Central
  Administration, go to Backup and Restore > Export a site or list.
  Choose your list, and click Start Export
- Copy the exported list (.cmp file) to your desktop and change the extension to .cab. You can then extract it using a software like WinRar.
- Open the SystemData.XML file with an editor like NotePad++ and change the version from 14.0.0.0 to 15.0.0.0 , and the build version from your 14.0.x.x to 15.0.x.x (depending on the build you have on both your farms). Here is a screenshot with before and afte
- Now we have to repackage it as a .cab file. I used a software called CabPack. Select your Source and Destination. Change the CabinetNameTemplate if you want, and click on OK.
- Change the extension from .cab to .cmp
- Copy the .cmp file back on the network share or directly on the SharePoint 2013 Server.
- Open SharePoint 2013 Management Shell as an administrator. Run this command by changing the parameters of course! Import-SPWeb -Identity http://teamsite.vlad.local/ -Path \sp2010-itest\Exports\MyCusttomList.cmp -Verbose
- Open up your SharePoint Site and your list should be there

source:http://absolute-sharepoint.com/2013/08/how-to-move-a-list-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013.html

**Method 2)** 
I am sure you already have you 2013 farm up and running.

- Backup the Content Database of the Site Collection in which the list
  is. (SharePoint 2010)
- Create a Temporary Web Application in the SharePoint 2013 Farm.
- Run SharePoint 2013 Management Shell as an administrator, and run the
  following command to dismount the content database:

  Get-SPContentDatabase -WebApplication http://sitename.com | Dismount-SPContentDatabase
- Restore the Backup you took in Step 1, on the SQL Instance hosting
  your SharePoint 2013 Farm. Make sure you give the farm account
  db_owner permissions on the database.
- In the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell, run the following command.

  Mount-SPContentDatabase MyDatabase -WebApplication http://sitename.com
- Navigate to the Site Collection, and if you didn’t have too many
  development and custom things done, it should open no problem. Make
  sure the list you want to export is ok.
- Go in the Central Administration, go to Backup and Restore > Export a
  site or list. Choose your list, and click Start Export
- Open SharePoint 2013 Management Shell as an administrator. Run this
  command by changing the parameters of course! `

  Import-SPWeb -Identity http://teamsite.vlad.local/ -Path \sp2010itest\Exports\MyCusttomList.cmp -Verbose
- Open up your SharePoint Site and your list should be there

Comment: Thanks Waqas,you made my day. Let me try to implement the same.

Answer (score 1):

For simple migration you can use:

1. Open both libraries in explorer view and simply copy paste the files on both the libraries.
2. Using powershell script
   http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Copy-all-SharePoint-Files-0999c53f
3. Try saving your list as template and create new document library with that template.
4. Free tool available at codeplex to migrate documents

http://spdocsmigrator.codeplex.com/